# Reproject map in OpenLayers

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

How can I reproject map in OpenLayers?

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Accessible Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./libs/ol.css">
    <script src="./libs/ol.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" include='proj4' src="./proj4js-2.8.0/dist/proj4.js"></script>
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
    <script>
    
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my main.js

```
var projection_3031 = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:3031',
    extent:[-948.75 -543592.47,5817.41 -3333128.95],
    units: 'm',
    axisOrientation: 'neu'
    });
    proj4.defs("EPSG:3031","+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-71 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");
    //结合proj4在ol3中自定义坐标系,以4326为例(3857同理)
    ol.proj.addProjection(projection_3031);
    ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3031",
        function(coordinate) {
            return proj4("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3031",coordinate);
        },
        function(coordinate) {
            return proj4("EPSG:3031","EPSG:4326",coordinate);;
        }
    );
    /*result=ol.proj.transform([118,32],'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3031');
    console.log(result)
    */
var map = new ol.Map({
    target : 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
    view : new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2,
        projection: 'EPSG:3031',
    })
});
```

my console.log(result) works well, but the map is blank. I want to know how can I get the right map with EPSG:3031.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of OpenLayers you will need to register proj4.  Also your extent is smaller than that usually used for EPSG:3031 and OSM has no coverage close to the poles.  This will show the whole of Antarctica:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:3031","+proj=stere +lat_0=-90 +lat_ts=-71 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

ol.proj.get('EPSG:3031').setExtent([-3299207.53, -3333134.03, 3299207.53, 3333134.03]);

var map = new ol.Map({
    target : 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
    view : new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1,
        projection: 'EPSG:3031',
    })
});
```

Comment: thank you very much with your help！

Comment: If answer helped you solve you problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems know that problem was resolved.